# set aria-checked property of radio to true after fireEvent.click in react-testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to set the aria-checked property of radiobutton to true after fireEvent.click. I do not want to do it by setAttribute but onclick.

I have tried the following code to test my component.

Radiobutton.js

```
function Radiobutton(props) {
  const { label, onClick, onKeyPress, isChecked } = props;

  return (
    <div
      className="radiobutton"
      role="radio"
      onClick={onClick}
      onKeyDown={onKeyPress}
      aria-checked={isChecked}
      tabIndex={0}
      value={label}
    >
      <span className="radiobutton__label">{label}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Radiobutton.test.jsx

```
test("radiobuttons must use click", () => {
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  const { container } = render(
    <Radiobutton onClick={handleChange} isChecked={false} label="Dummy Radio" />
  );
  const radiobtn = getByRole(container, "radio");
  fireEvent.click(radiobtn);
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(radiobtn.getAttribute("aria-checked")).toBe("true");

});
```

I am able to call the handleChange function but unable to change the value of aria-checked. I'm getting the following error.

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "true"
    Received: "false"

      30 |   expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    > 31 |   expect(radiobtn.getAttribute("aria-checked")).toBe("true");
         |                                                 ^
      32 |   console.log(prettyDOM(radiobtn));
      33 | });

      at Object.toBe (src/__tests__/radiobutton.test.jsx:31:49)
```

I'm new to testing. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your component's code handling change happens on parent element. To simulate this behavior in test you need to update `isChecked` prop once `handleChange` has been called.

Up to [maintainer's comment](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/65#issuecomment-385529996) the way to achieve that is re-rendering the same element into same container with different props:

```js
test("radiobuttons must use click", () => {
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  const { container } = render(
    <Radiobutton onClick={handleChange} isChecked={false} label="Dummy Radio" />
  );
  const radiobtn = getByRole(container, "radio");
  fireEvent.click(radiobtn);
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  render(<Radiobutton onClick={handleChange} isChecked={true} label="Dummy Radio" />, { container });
  expect(radiobtn.getAttribute("aria-checked")).toBe("true");
});
```

Also you may put re-rendering logic inside of `handleChange.mockImplementation` but I believe it makes test case harder to read:

```js
test("radiobuttons must use click", () => {
  let isChecked = false;
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  const { container } = render(
    <Radiobutton onClick={handleChange} isChecked={false} label="Dummy Radio" />
  );
  handleChange.mockImplementation(() => {
    isChecked = !isChecked;
    render(<Radiobutton onClick={handleChange} isChecked={isChecked} label="Dummy Radio" />, { container });
  });
  const radiobtn = getByRole(container, "radio");
  fireEvent.click(radiobtn);
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(radiobtn.getAttribute("aria-checked")).toBe("true");
});
```

Another drawback is that `handleChange` logic should be somewhere in parent component so you are rather testing your own mock than testing your app.

To me it looks really messy and does not provide any additional value to you since in real world it would be up to parent's component if it update `isChecked` after `onClick` or not.

So I propose you to split test case into two. First checks if clicking calls `onClick` handler. And separate checks if `isChecked={true}` provides `aria-checked`. Maybe even better to have 3rd to check if `isChecked={false}` does not inject `aria-checked` attribute.

```js
test('provides aria-checked if isChecked is truly', () => {
  const { container } = render(<Radiobutton isChecked={true} />);
  const radiobtn = getByRole(container, "radio");
  expect(radiobtn.getAttribute("aria-checked")).toBe("true");
});
test('does not provide aria-checked if isChecked is falsy', () => {
  const { container } = render(<Radiobutton />);
  const radiobtn = getByRole(container, "radio");
  expect(radiobtn.getAttribute("aria-checked")).not.toBe("true");
});
```

Comment: There isn't any way by which my fireEvent.click(radiobtn); changes the aria-checked to true and then I can compare if its true?

Comment: actually, you may put re-rendering logic into `handleChange` mock but it would make test much less maintainable. included into answer.

Comment: Is there any way to test if only 1 radiobutton is checked after clicking a radiobutton on my parent (radiogroup) component?
```
  it("should click on text", () => {
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
const { container } = render(<Radiogroup onClick={handleChange} />);
    const dialogContainer = getAllByRole(container, "radio");
    dialogContainer[0].setAttribute("aria-checked", "true");
    dialogContainer.forEach(key => {
      //
      // Code to check if only 1 radiobutton was clicked
      //
    });
  });
```

Comment: please create separate question to keep it still useful for others